# How to stop files inside moved directories (and newly created files) from automatically opening in editor (PyCharm 2020.1)

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

I am using PyCharm 2020.1. When I create a new file, PyCharm automatically opens it in the editor. Also when I move a directory, PyCharm opens all the files inside the directory in the editor.

Sometimes it's tens of files opened at once. This behavior is frustrating and I would like to turn it off, but have not been able to find where in Preferences to do so.

Someone please help me figure out how to stop newly created files and files inside moved folders from automatically opening in editor. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can't open a new file via PyCharm, unless you create it via the Terminal tab on the bottom, for example:
`touch test.py`

When you move a directory into a new directory, there should be a checkmark on a popup saying "Open moved files in editor", so you probably have that checked.